# How do I override default attributes in Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I'm new to Chef, though I understand the concept now. I understand the concept of default vs. override attributes, but how do I do it within an environment? Particularly, I want to override data bag attributes that someone else defined. For example, if we have the following data bag

```
{
   "id" : "common",
   "some_server" : "www.some_server.com"
}
```

I want ALL my recipes in my "environment" to override "some_server" with "www.my_server.com" Does that make sense? Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files.html#attribute-precedenc

Comment: I've read all the docs, and even have books. NONE of them answer my question directly though. The link you gave doesn't even mention environments.

Comment: I am confused if you want data bags or environments.  Data bags are not really attributes, see: http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_data_bags.html  If you want to override them you have to add in more structure.  See the example: http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_environments.html#save-in-a-data-bag  If the current data bag is that simple you will likely have to work with that developer to expand on it.

Comment: 3. and 12. both talk about environments. Your question does not make sense - data bags != attributes.

Comment: Aaron, that data bag above is just an example, the real one has more items than that. Like I said, I'm new to Chef so if I sound confused I am. In general, I want to know how to use variables defined in an environment I've assigned to my role. Specifically, I want to know the process where I change my environment in my role, and voila, the values for my attributes change, without changing anything in my recipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the advice from this [article][1] 
  [1]: http://www.getchef.com/blog/2014/01/23/attributes-or-data-bags-what-should-i-use/ , 
which recommends to use data bags for "global" values, that is, values that will be used by ALL recipes, regardless of environments, and to code variables that are environment-specific in my environments, and set my nodes to that environment. Therefore the following is discouraged to be in the data bags

```
{
  "id":"common",
  "devel": {
    "some_server": ""www.some_server.com"
  },
  "staging": {
    "some_server: "www.my_server.com"
  }
}
```

Instead I do the following

Say in my setup_server cookbook, I may have the following attribute defined in attributes/default.rb

```
default.setup_server.a_server = "www.some_server.com"
```

...and a recipe that simply does

```
puts "server " + "#{node.setup_server.a_server}"
```

If I assign my node to the _default environment, the output will be:

```
server = www.some_server.com
```

I now create an environment called my_environment, and define the following overridden attribute

```
environments/my_environment.json:
{
  "name"  : "my_environment",
  "override_attributes" : {
    "setup_server" : {
      "a_server": "www.my_server.com"
    }
  }
}
```

If I now assign my cookbook to the "my_environment" environment, and rerun the recipe, I now get

```
server = www.my_server.com
```

Answer (score 1):

A data bag is just a bag of data - a list of key-value pairs. It has nothing to do with environments, attributes and anything else. If you want your data bag provide different data based on environment, you have to teach it.

One option is to have environment name as part of data:

```
{
  "id":"common",
  "devel": {
    "some_server": ""www.some_server.com"
  },
  "staging": {
    "some_server: "www.my_server.com"
  }
}
```

And then you can read your data in recipe like that:

```
data_bag[node.environment]["some_server"]
```

provided you have *devel* and *staging* environments.